# Open new python shell on C-c C-c in python-mode.el

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I have a small GTK python application that imports a package (Twisted) that may not be loaded twice.

If I run my application in emacs with python-mode.el and press C-c C-c, the application gets executed in a python shell window.
If I now close the application, the python shell stays up and running. If I now press C-c C-c again, emacs "reuses" the old python process and thus I run into problems because I'm installing a Twisted reactor twice.

Is it possible to have python-mode.el open a new shell window each time I execute a buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `python.el`, a new inferior process is launched in a new buffer if the `python-buffer` variable is set to `nil`. Therefore, it's possible to advise the `python-send-buffer` function to reset that variable to `nil` after every invocation, thereby forcing a new Python process to be executed for every subsequent `python-send-buffer` command. Something like the following should work:

```
(defadvice
  python-send-buffer
  (after python-send-buffer-new-proc activate)
  (setq python-buffer nil))

(ad-activate python-send-buffer)
```

I know that your post was asking for help with `python-mode.el`, but I thought it might be helpful to mention this anyway, as I'd surprised if `python-mode.el` doesn't use a similar mechanism. If I have time, I'll try to look into it.

Edit: the `python-mode.el` package uses the command `py-shell` to initiate a new inferior Python process. I found [a mailing list posting](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2007-May/004365.html) in which a user provides an *ad hoc* function that appears to do what you need.

By the way, it might be worth considering that trying to alter the default behavior of `python-mode` isn't the best approach to this problem. I don't know what your code does, and I'm not particularly familiar with Twisted, but it seems to me that experiencing major errors when evaluating your code a second time within the same session could be a sign of a more fundamental design problem. I fail to see how it could be a matter of multiple `imports` of the same module being the issue, as Python modules are only loaded once, with successive `import` statements having no effect (for that, an explicit `reload` or `execfile()` is required). If I'm completely off-base here, I apologize, but I felt this possibility might merit mention.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. To the Twisted problem: I do an
`from twisted.internet import gtk3reactor
gtk3reactor.install()`
as per Twisted manual which causes the problem when being evaluated a second time. Is there a standard way of checking whether a module has been imported before?

Comment: @gnirx, normally, importing a module a second time has no effect, and if it does have some effect, particularly an error-producing one, it's probably an indication that the code should be restructured in some way. That said, maybe your case is an exception -- I don't know enough about the particulars of Twisted to be certain either way. If you really want to check whether a module has been imported, `import sys` and check whether it's present in `sys.modules`. Keep in mind, that's generally considered kludgy, and it'd be better to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 2):

python-mode.el comes with a command py-execute-buffer-dedicated,
 opening a new and reserved process for it